# How to find a matched strings with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a file and I want to find the matched sentences which have a format such as:

```
###### 1. What's the output?
###### 586. which of the following suggestions is correct?
###### 100. Which one is true?
```

I tried this regexp:

```
content.match(/^\#{6}\s(\w+\W+)+\?$/gm)
```

But it matchs the whole paragraph not only the matched sentences. How can I fix that?

Comment: Maybe `/^\#{6}[ \t].*\?$/gm`

Comment: Assuming there is always gonna be a space, number, dot space then a phrase that ends with "?" 
try this: `/^#{6}\s\d+\.(.+?)\?$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant `[\w\W]` rather than `(\w\W)`, since the latter does not match. The character class `[\w\W]` is going to match every character, including line breaks. `+` matches greedily, so the match goes all the way to the last `?` found in the text. If you can assume each question will be on a single line, then just use `.` instead.

```
content.match(/^\#{6}\s.+\?$/gm)
```